# Schedule Task every month Python

Tags: python, timer

I need to create a function to send 100 messages after six months. I know how to create the messaging part
But i don't know how to create a timer can someone please send a function to do so.

Comment: Hello, we do not write full programs for people, please read the rules and post the code you have already composed.

Answer (score 2):

Hi 
You could use [crontab](https://crontab.guru/) 
Open the cron job page

```
crontab -e
```

And then add this line to the end of the file

```
0 0 1 * *  /usr/bin/python /yourPath/example.py
```

(That is the place that you install your python /usr/bin/python ) 
I hope it works and helps you :)

#### And if you are using windows

Do these steps 
1.Go to Start > Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools > Task Scheduler 
2.In the right panel click on Create Basic Task 
3.Enter a name like "run python command" and click Next 
4.On the next page define the scheduled dates when the task has to run. Every night should be often enough. 
5.On the Action page select Start a program 
And for more info look at this [link](https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Usage/How_to_add_a_cron_job_on_Windows.html)

Comment: I have to add this in my installation path bin folder? Or somewhere else

Comment: what is your os?

Comment: windows 7 or 10 i have both